# Can a CNAME record point to a domain handled by another DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

Assume a CNAME record pointing to a domain name that is handled by a different server than the one the CNAME record resides on. For example

- domain `aaaaaaaa.com` has authoritative name server `dns.aisp.net`
- its zone file contains record `www 7200 IN CNAME www.bbbbbbbb.com`
- domain `bbbbbbbb.com` has authoritative name server `dns.bisp.org`
- its zone file contains record `www 7200 IN A 222.222.222.222`

Is it fine that `dns.aisp.net` is not the authoritative domain server for `bbbbbbbb.com` pointed to by the CNAME record, and contains no information about `bbbbbbbb.com` or `www.bbbbbbbb.com`? Will it prevent any modern software/browser/OS from accessing `www.aaaaaaaa.com`? I can restrict to http and https, if that helps.

Comment: In your questions please refrain from using random domain names and use either your *own domain* or one of the [RFC 6761](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761#section-6.5) reserved domain names such as  `example.com`, `example.org`  or similar . Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions.

Comment: In short, you can point a CNAME record to any hostname, regardless of who owns and operates that domain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it fine that dns.aisp.net is not the authoritative domain server
>   for bbbbbbbb.com pointed to by the CNAME record, and contains no
>   information about bbbbbbbb.com or www.bbbbbbbb.com?

Yes. This is fine.

> Will it prevent any modern software/browser/OS from accessing
>   www.aaaaaaaa.com?

No.

As HBruijn mentions in his comment, the CNAME can point to anywhere. If you owned the domain `example.com`, you could create a CNAME for `notmydomain` which points to `www.example.org` which you don't own/manage and users pointing their browser to `notmydomain.example.com` would connect to `www.example.org`